# how can one find categories of a wikipedia page using just links of pages?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is there any API by which one can get all the categories of a page using the title or page id or url of that page? I tried searching on net but all I could find was getting dumps for specific categories. Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: 'I could find was getting dumps for specific categories' could you please tell where to find it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The API you are looking for is here https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
This is the media wiki API and has lots of documentation.

As said above you are looking for prop=categories
so... ***?format=xml&action=query&prop=categories&titles=Google*** for example

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=categories&titles=Google

If you are looking to use this in a program it may be worth looking at the following Wikipedia page that has a series of classes and libraries for various languages to deal with handling the Wikipedia API e.t.c

**Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#Programming_languages_and_libraries**

Answer (score 8):

MediaWiki (Wikipedia's software) has an API and you can indeed do a query to get the categories of a page. For example, the following returns the categories of the page `Google` in the English language Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=categories&titles=Google

Note that not all categories are returned in one response. You'll see an element called `query-continue` which provides additional information on how the next query should be formulated which will give you more categories.

References:

- [MediaWiki API documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query)
- [MediaWiki API on categories of a page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query_-_Properties#categories_.2F_cl)

Comment: It's probably better to add `cllimit=max` to the query. That way, you have smaller number of queries and you might not even need more queries (I doubt any page has more than 500 categories).